# Labelling of $3$-regular graph with $2$ labels with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I want to label the vertices of a $3$-regular graph, using $2$ labels (say, Up, Down), with the constraint that if all the neighbors of a vertex are Up, the vertex must be Down; otherwise it must be Up.

For such a graph with $n$ vertices, how many different labellings are possible (as a function of $n$)?

Comment: Recall that a graph is 2-colorable if and only if it is bipartite, and furthermore the number of 2-colorings is the number of ways to partition the graph into two independent sets. I don't think being 3-regular with no other assumptions helps you here. Consider the Petersen graph and $K_{3,3}$ for example.

Comment: The coloring in question is not a coloring in a legal coloring sense

Comment: Oops - sorry imu96 - I just edited my question - it is about graph labelling as such rather than coloring, but thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: Ah true. My mistake.

Comment: Since no two neighboring vertices are labeled Down - we are talking about independent set. Moreover it is a maximal independent set. So the question is how many maximal independent sets are there for a $3$-regular graph on $n$ vertices?

Comment: MathOverflow: [Labelling (with constraints) of vertices of a 3-regular graph](https://mathoverflow.net/q/337814). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) contains very reasonable advice about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: Maybe one needs to be more specific about which 3-regular graph is being considered to answer this question - if so - I am thinking of the Circular Ladder Graph ${CL}_n$